# git: how to turn a clone into a new branch?

Tags: git

I've cloned master from my repository and have been making a bunch of edits and local commits. I've now realised this should be a new branch in my remote repository. Normally I'd just push to the remote system, how do I push as a new branch to the remote repos?

Comment: @FelixKling yes it looks like it's a duplicate of that question. I used the suggestion there and it worked perfectly for me, thanks!

Comment: @new299 -- Be sure to check Mike Weller's link as well, as you may want to "back up" your master branch to agree with origin/master. My answer basically duplicates the answers given to that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have't pushed anything yet and your history looks something like

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
^                   ^
|                   |
origin/master       master
```

You can just do the following:

```
git branch feature
git reset origin/master
```

to get this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
^                   ^
|                   |
|                   feature
origin/master,master
```

Comment: Just as I was going to hit "post" you beat me to it! +1 (Though in retrospect, this is a dup .. but still +1)